# ¿Cómo puedo obtener la cadena de conexión que esta en el web.config?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Estoy tratando de obtener la cadena de conexion del `Web.config` de mi aplicacion `asp.net`  Visual Basic, intenté con el código de aquí pero me sale error

```
Dim strConnString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("LocalSqlServer").ConnectionString
```

Comment: ¿Que error te da?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que funcione, deberías tener lo siguiente:

Primero en el web.config

```
 <connectionStrings>
   <add name="LocalSqlServer" providerName="TuProvider" connectionString="TuCadenaDeConexion" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Para leer el valor, en la aplicación deberías escribir:

```
Dim strConnString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("LocalSqlServer").ConnectionString
```

Nota: No te olvides de agregar esta sentencia al inicio del código

```
Imports System.Configuration
```

(Y que la dll `System.Configuration.dll` esté referenciada)

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que tenere en cuenta que en tu archivo de configuracion el name del connectionString debe ser igual al del codigo "**LocalSqlServer**"